# Find tables that are copied / duplicate structure within database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014-express

I have 1000's of tables in SQL Server that have each been created from CSV files. The data in each table is all similar with each table representing a different day.

The problem I am having, is that there are lots of variations in the structure of the tables as well as the names of columns.

Some tables do however have matching structures, and I thought a good starting point for combining the data would be to combine all the data in those one together.

I have been looking for a way to query the database in order to find these tables that have the same structure but have been as yet unsuccessful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Normally you would use a staging table to import the data and then copy/move it to the real tables in your DB.

Comment: I was initially going to do something similar to that. I changed my mind when I found there were over 400 columns in each file and started getting them in to the database while I tried to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the tables are truly identical, then try this out. I actually use it to create your insert statements and it can drop the old tables if you want it to.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.table1;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.table2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.table2;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.table3') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.table3;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.table4') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.table4;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.table5') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.table5;

CREATE TABLE table1 (ID INT,FirstName VARCHAR(25),LastName NVARCHAR(25),EntryDate DATETIME,AvgScore NUMERIC(18,6)); --table1
CREATE TABLE table2 (ID INT,FirstName VARCHAR(25),LastName NVARCHAR(25),EntryDate DATETIME,AvgScore NUMERIC(18,6)); --matches table1
CREATE TABLE table3 (ID INT,FirstName VARCHAR(25),LastName NVARCHAR(25),EntryDate DATETIME); --table3
CREATE TABLE table4 (ID INT,FirstName VARCHAR(25),LastName NVARCHAR(25),EntryDate DATETIME); --matches table3
CREATE TABLE table5 (ID INT,FirstName VARCHAR(25),LastName NVARCHAR(25),EntryDate DATETIME,AvgScore NUMERIC(18,6)); --matches table1




WITH CTE_matching_Tables
AS
(
    SELECT
            A.TABLE_NAME primaryTable,
            A.total_columns,
            COUNT(*) AS matching_columns,
            B.TABLE_NAME AS matchedTable
    FROM        (SELECT *, MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) OVER (PARTITION BY Table_NAME) AS total_columns FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS) A
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT *, MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) OVER (PARTITION BY Table_NAME) AS total_columns FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS) B
    ON      A.TABLE_NAME < B.TABLE_NAME
        AND A.ORDINAL_POSITION = B.ORDINAL_POSITION
        AND A.total_columns = B.total_columns
        AND A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
        AND A.DATA_TYPE = B.DATA_TYPE
        AND A.IS_NULLABLE = B.IS_NULLABLE
        AND (       (A.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = B.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) 
                OR  (A.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL AND B.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL)
            )
        AND (       (A.NUMERIC_PRECISION = B.NUMERIC_PRECISION) 
                OR  (A.NUMERIC_PRECISION IS NULL AND B.NUMERIC_PRECISION IS NULL)
            )
        AND (       (A.NUMERIC_SCALE = B.NUMERIC_SCALE) 
                OR  (A.NUMERIC_SCALE IS NULL AND B.NUMERIC_SCALE IS NULL)
            )
        AND (       (A.DATETIME_PRECISION = B.DATETIME_PRECISION) 
                OR  (A.DATETIME_PRECISION IS NULL AND B.DATETIME_PRECISION IS NULL)
            )
    GROUP BY A.TABLE_NAME,A.total_columns,B.TABLE_NAME
    HAVING A.total_columns = COUNT(*)
)

--CTE has all table matches. I find the lowest occurring primaryTable for each matchedTable
    --That way in my case table2 and table 5 insert into table 1 even though table2 and table5 also match
SELECT  'INSERT INTO ' + MIN(primaryTable) + ' SELECT * FROM ' + matchedTable + '; DROP TABLE ' + matchedTable + ';'
FROM CTE_matching_Tables
GROUP BY matchedTable
```

Results:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2; DROP TABLE table2;
INSERT INTO table3 SELECT * FROM table4; DROP TABLE table4;
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table5; DROP TABLE table5;
```

Comment: This worked well thanks. I have however had to amend it to include a check that the number of columns matched by name was equal to the total column count.

Comment: Oh good catch. I deleted that line and accidentally forgot to re-add it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is checking for tables with exact number of columns and if the columns types matches. Note, that the order is not important. For example, if you have two tables like this:

```
Table01
Column01 INT
Column02 BIT

Table02
Column01 BIT
Column02 INT
```

there are going to be matched as having same structured.

---

The code below is simple - for each table we are creating `CSV` list with its columns types.

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [name] SYSNAME
    ,[value] VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([name], [value])
SELECT T.[name]                                                                 
      ,ColumnsTypesCSV.[value]
FROM [sys].[tables] T
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + CAST([system_type_id] AS VARCHAR(12))
            FROM [sys].[columns] C
            WHERE T.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
            ORDER BY [system_type_id]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    )
) ColumnsTypesCSV ([value]);
```

A select from the table looks like this:

[image]

Now, we are going to do exactly the same thing but this time the grouping is made by the columns types `CSV` list:

```
SELECT DS.[value]
      ,NamesCSV.[value]
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + [name]
            FROM @DataSource D
            WHERE DS.[value] = D.[value]
            ORDER BY [name]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    )
) NamesCSV ([value]);
```

I am testing this code in the `AdventureWorks2012` database and it actually found tables matching in it:

[image]

Of course this is just a start point. You can check for other things, too. For example, for each column type id you can add if the columns is `NULL` or `NOT NULL` like this:

```
TYPEID|NOTNULL,TYPEID|NULL...
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a wealth of data in the informational view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

This will give you (among other things) the table name, order of columns, column names, and column definitions.

So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
;
-- Create a list of table pairs.  If you have reason to believe that
-- some tables are more likely to be similar than others, you can
-- modify this CTE as you need to.
with A as (
    select    T1.table_name
         ,    t2.TABLE_NAME as other_table_Name
    from    information_Schema.TABLES t1
        join information_schema.tables t2
            on    t1.TABLE_NAME < t2.TABLE_NAME
)
-- Pick all the pairs of table names ...
select   * 
from     A
where    NOT  exists (
    -- where the first table does NOT have any columns ...
    select  1
    from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c1
    where    A.TABLE_NAME = C1.TABLE_NAME
        and not exists (
        -- ... that are NOT found in the second table ...
            select  1
            from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c2
            where   c2.Table_Name = A.other_table_Name
               AND  c1.ordinal_position = c2.ordinal_position
               and  c1.data_type = c2.data_type
               and  ((c1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is null and 
                     c2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is null) or               
                     c1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = c2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)
        )
    )
    and    NOT  exists (
    -- ... and the second table doesn't have any columns ...
        select  1
        from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c1
        where    A.OTHER_TABLE_NAME = C1.TABLE_NAME
             and not exists (
             -- that are not also found in the first table!
                select 1
                from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c2
                where    c2.Table_Name = A.TABLE_NAME
                  AND    c1.ordinal_position = c2.ordinal_position
                  and c1.data_type = c2.data_type
                  and ((c1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is null and 
                       c2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is null) or 
                       c1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = c2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)
         )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I used checksum and a bunch of columns from information_schema.columns. This will give you a list of tables and any tables with the same magic number(sum of checksum) are matches.

```
declare @s1   sysname
declare @n1   sysname
declare @olds1 sysname
declare @oldn1 sysname
declare @curmagicnum decimal(18,0)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#alltables','U') is not null
    drop table #alltables 

create table #alltables (schema_name sysname,
                   table_name sysname,
                   magicnum decimal(18,0))


select top 1 @s1 = TABLE_SCHEMA, @n1=table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES order by TABLE_SCHEMA,table_name

    while (1=1)
    begin

    select   @curmagicnum= SUM(CAST(
      CHECKSUM (COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_DEFAULT, IS_NULLABLE,    
      DATA_TYPE,    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,   
      NUMERIC_PRECISION,    NUMERIC_SCALE,  DATETIME_PRECISION) 
as decimal(18,0))) 

from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
where TABLE_NAME = @n1 and TABLE_SCHEMA=@s1

    insert into #alltables values (@s1,@n1,@curmagicnum)

    set @oldn1 = @n1
    set @olds1 = @s1
    select top 1 @s1 = TABLE_SCHEMA, @n1=table_name 



from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  
        where TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME> @s1+'.'+@n1
        order by TABLE_SCHEMA,table_name
        if @@ROWCOUNT=0
            break

    end
    ;


     with t1 as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by magicnum order by table_name) as count1 from #alltables)

    select schema_name,table_name,magicnum 
    from #alltables 
    where magicnum in (select magicnum from t1  where count1> 1)
        order by magicnum,table_name
```